# Remove shadow/background glow on highcharts data label?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

If you check out my http://jsfiddle.net/WOUNDEDStevenJones/oe1vcmqj/1/, the red labels on the chart have a subtle white glow behind them (in at least Chrome and FF).  How do I remove that white glow?  Or worst case at least change the color to the same blue so it blends in?

I've tried using `shadow`, `backgroundColor`, and other properties from their API (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels), but can't figure out what is defining that glow behind the red text.

```
plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'red',
                inside: false,
                xHigh: -45,
                xLow: -9999999,
                shadow: "#ff0000",
                formatter: function () {
                    if (this.point.high) {
                        var myDate = new Date(this.y);
                        var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(),myDate.getUTCMonth(),myDate.getUTCDate());
                        return '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%e',newDateMs) + '</b>';
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try text-shadow:none;

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Set `dataLabels.styles.textShadow` to `false`.

```
    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: { // or general options: "series: { ... }"
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'red',
                style: {
                    textShadow: false 
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oe1vcmqj/2/

**EDIT**:

Since Highcharts 5.0.3, the option name is `textOutline`.

```
    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: { // or general options: "series: { ... }"
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'red',
                style: {
                    textOutline: false 
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oe1vcmqj/49/

**EDIT v2.0**:

Since Highcharts 5.0.13, the `textOutline` option should be a `string`, so to disable outline, set `textOutline: 'none'`.

```
    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: { // or general options: "series: { ... }"
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'red',
                style: {
                    textOutline: 'none' 
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s7ejvhmu/

Comment: I came across the same question and find the demo fiddle still has white glow behind data labels. Similar issue can also be found in http://jsfiddle.net/2qrybqgn/ Maybe things has changed in highcharts 5?

Comment: You are right. That name was just changed (5.0.3-> changelog), see the edit above. Thanks!

Comment: can we set this option globally to all charts? I tried using this inside Highcharts.setOptions, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can, could you show example what have you tried? It should be simply `plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style.textOutline`.

Comment: Worked, thanks. I was using plotOptions.columnrange instead of plotOptions.series.

Comment: That's right, but textOutline don't take boolean value; textOutline: '' is working

Comment: Updated answer, thank you! It should be `'none'` but it seems `''` works too.

Answer (score 6):

```
dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.y}',
       style: {
          textOutline: false 
           }
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

use `text-shadow:none !important;` for the tag `tspan`

**CSS**

```
tspan{
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:none !important;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m0100734/)

Comment: this is a valid solution by the way, but I think somebody downvoted it because it's not a Highcharts solution, and using `!important` is generally frowned upon (meaning there's probably a better way of accomplishing this, not that `!important` isn't a useful option)

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones !important is added as a CSS property to use it where ever necessary,since high harts or charts are used in a certain pages only and tspan is not used generaly,!important usage is valid here..!! Some people just down vote where ever they see !important.

Comment: I know, I'm with you on that.  I'm just commenting so others looking at this question realize that this would still work and is a valid option, even through somebody downvoted this answer for an unknown reason

Answer (score 1):

worked for me...

```
dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'white',
                style: {
                    // textShadow: false 
                    textOutline: false
                }
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530807/1499877

Comment: i was trying with "// textShadow: false" but that one "textOutline: false" worked for me.

Comment: The accepted answer lists both `textShadow: false` and `textOutline: false` depending on the Highcharts version

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.4.0

use

```
dataLabels: {
  dropShadow: false
}
```

Comment: Please add supporting info to your answer to improve it.