# How are textshadow false

Tags: javascript

How to remove shadows from numbers in charts?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
           plotBackgroundColor: null,
           plotBorderWidth: null,
           plotShadow: null
        },
        title: {
           text: 'STATUS',
           align: 'center',
           style:
           {
            fontSize:'14px',
              color: '#000000',
              fontWeight: 'bold'
           }
        },
        credits: {
         enabled: false
      },   
        legend: {    
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          layout: 'vertical',
          floating: true,
          itemStyle: {
              color: '#000000',
              fontSize: 12
          },
          symbolRadius: 0,
    y: 115,
        },
        plotOptions: {
           pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              size: '100%',
              center: [ '50%', '25%' ],
              dataLabels: {
                 enabled: true,
                 distance: -35,
                 color: '#ffffff',
                 style: {
                     fontSize: 13
                 },
                 formatter: function() {
                    if(this.point.color=='#01a698'){
                        return '<span>' + this.y +'</span>';
                    }
                    if(this.point.color=='#77c646'){
                        return '<span>' + this.y +'</span>';
                    }
                    if(this.point.color=='#fd4c01'){
                        return '<span>' + this.y +'</span>';
                    }
                    if(this.point.color=='#f7921d'){
                        return '<span>' + this.y +'</span>';
                    }
                    if(this.point.color=='#f7af33'){
                        return '<span>' + this.y +'</span>';
                    }

                 }
              },
              showInLegend: true
           },
        },
        series: [{
           type: 'pie',
           data: [
              {
                  name: '1',
                   y: 19,
                  color: '#01a698'
              },
              {
                  name: '2',
                   y: 11,
                  color: '#77c646'
              },
              {
                  name: '3',
                   y: 12,
                  color: '#fd4c01'
              }
              ,
              {
                  name: '4',
                   y: 17,
                  color: '#f7921d'
              }
     ,
              {
                  name: '5',
                   y: 13,
                  color: '#f7af33'
              }
           ]
        }],
        tooltip : {
         enabled : false 
        }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height:250px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `textOutline: false` to the `style` object in the config:

```
style: {
  fontSize: 13,
  textOutline: false
},
```

This has also already been answered here: [Remove shadow/background glow on highcharts data label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025789/remove-shadow-background-glow-on-highcharts-data-label)